AttributeConverter<Boolean, Integer> no longer working after upgrading Hibernate 5.x to 6.x
I'm migrating my project from Spring Boot 2.7.17 which uses Hibernate 5.6.15 to Spring Boot 3.0.13 which uses Hibernate 6.1.7.
In my code I have an entity with a boolean field which is mapped to an integer database column:
...
@Column(name="ENTITY_TYPE")
@Convert(converter = my.business.persist.util.BooleanToIntConverter.class)
private Boolean entityType;

With Hibernate 5.6.15 this all worked fine. Now my unit tests fail with error:
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Boolean (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Boolean are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at my.business.persist.util.BooleanToIntConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(BooleanToIntConverter.java:1)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.convert.internal.JpaAttributeConverterImpl.toRelationalValue(JpaAttributeConverterImpl.java:99)
... 111 more

I noticed Hibernate 6 has its own implementation to do the same: NumericBooleanConverter. Also using this converter I get exactly the same exception.
My converter implementation (after changing javax.* to jakarta.*):
import jakarta.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import jakarta.persistence.Converter;

@Converter
public class BooleanToIntConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean value) {
        if(value!=null)
            return value? 1 : 0;
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(Integer value) {
        if(value!=null)
             return value == 1;
        return false;
    }
}

Does anybody knows how to fix this ? I first try to migrate to 3.0 and afterwards migrate to 3.1 (and maybe 3.2).

Not able to reproduce your error, could you provide a minimal reproducible example?
